# What is Snoke’s guards’ armor made of?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

The armor itself seems to have been

> much better able to withstand direct lightsaber contact than most other materials such weapons encounter.

I remember reading somewhere that

> Mandalorian armor was specifically designed to withstand lightsabers. Could this be of the same type?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. This armour is not of Mandalorian design, as far as we're aware. The film's [Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary) describes it thusly;

> ARMOURED GUARDIANS
>
> *The layered armour of the Praetorian Guard is **a high tech onion-skin
>   of laminate, impregnated with conductive wirepaths that, once powered,
>   create an intense local magnetic field.** Once this energy-intensive
>   field activates, the powered plates can deflect blaster fire. **Even a
>   lightsaber will glance off**, though a directed thrust will penetrate
>   the shell.*
>
> *The mag-coils are costly, the plates heavy and mag-field exposure is
>   ultimately painful to the wearer, but such are the sacrifices of
>   protecting the Supreme Leader.*